# How do you purge taint?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

I realize that tainted regions are important for certain things in Thaumcraft, but I hate that it spreads so voraciously.

I've tried placing a ring of cobblestone around it to contain the area, but it inevitably spreads to new areas and I have constant damage control going on.

I don't want to disable it, so what is the best way to eliminate taint in an area?

Specifically, I am referring to Thamcraft that is included in the Direwolf20 modpack from Feed The Beast.  I believe this is Thaumcraft 4 (from [Direwolf20 Modpack Mods](https://feedthebeast.atlassian.net/wiki/display/PML/Direwolf20) )

Comment: You should clarify which ThaumCraft version you are talking about, there are three versions which are all vastly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop spreading of taint and remove taint by placing down an "Ethereal Bloom" where the taint is.

> Ethereal Blooms can be created in a crucible from the Shimmerleaf plants found growing under wild Silverwood Trees. They seem to show a strong resistance to Taint, and will clear a small area around them from this vile corruption. 
>   Source: http://thaumcraft-4.wikia.com/wiki/Ethereal_Blooms

Answer (score 1):

I've found that a good way to destroy an area of taint is make a large amount of Alumentum and blow it up. For taint to be eliminated, all the tainted blocks have to be destroyed. Obviously it's hard to do this with a shovel/pickaxe because of the effects of taint. You can also try TNT but I found alumentum easier because you're able to throw it at the taint.